# How to give Wordpress shortcode a dynamic Atribute?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, shortcode

I have build many shortcode to show somme data from a training cours. If y put a value, it works well.

```
[TEST_PHP cours = <script>document.write("1")</script>]
```

But if I try to use a const or a global var for the value, It doesent work, coursID = "" ?

```
<script>
    const coursID = "1";
</script>

[TEST_PHP cours = <script>document.write(coursID)</script>]
```

How to call a shortcode in Javascript with a const als attribute ?

Comment: are you trying to get your current post ID? and where do you use this shortcode?

Comment: No I have a DB with Info for all course and the shortcode link a php file to read and write the data from DB.

Comment: I am asking `coursID` is your current post ID in wordpress or what? how you're getting this, that's what I am asking. Are you using WordPress default functions or you've written your own things? Without proper details, it's hard to understand your issue and provide the better solution.

Comment: that is the ID from the cours in the DB. I define IT as a constant in javascript

Comment: and you have a custom course table? and what is the name of the table? and what php code you're writing to fetch the ID and write in javascript.

Comment: I have a PHP Code called by the TEST.PHP how make the job, it's not the Problem, like I said I put a value in the call it work. Problem is cause by usage of a constant in place of a value. Like it's render on Server I kann not use a variable, but with a constant it should work ?

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to provide any solution, when we don't know what you're writing, how you're writing, how your system works, how you're managing the global state, etc. just you know, you can't access the JS variable in PHP code. so you better use `global` method in PHP, if you're aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

**example of shortcode**

```
<?php 
function getgenie_elementor_render_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $attributes = shortcode_atts( array(
        'content_id' => 0,
    ), $atts );
    
    $content_id = $atts['content_id'];

    if ( !class_exists( '\Elementor\Plugin' ) ) {
        return 'builder not found';
    }

    if ( class_exists( '\Elementor\Core\Files\CSS\Post' ) ) {
        $css_file = new \Elementor\Core\Files\CSS\Post( $content_id );
        $css_file->enqueue();
    }
    
    $elementor_instance = \Elementor\Plugin::instance();

    return $elementor_instance->frontend->get_builder_content_for_display( $content_id );

}
add_shortcode( 'getgenie_elementor_render', 'getgenie_elementor_render_shortcode' );
```